# Why my main query is running successfully at the same time as subquery returns an error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

`select 1/0 as test` query returns an error "Divide by zero error encountered"

But this one works fine: 
`select count(*) from (select 1/0 as test) subquery`

Could anyone explain why it happens?

Answer (score 2):

It works, because sql server doesn't execute `1/0` from the subquery. You only want to count rows, sql server is smart enough to know that it is an additional action that is excess. For example these two statements don't work, because in these cases `1/0` must be executed.

```
select count(*),test from (select 1/0 as test) subquery group by test

select test from (select 1/0 as test) subquery
```

Answer (score -1):

The main query interacts with the subquery as normal SQL statement while the subquery is a purely mathematical problem which is you can not divide by zero.

Use this web site to compile your sql statement online:

https://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler

Answer (score -1):

"select * 1/0 as test;" this query will not return any error it will return the table with a value null in it so if you use it as a sub query in "select count(*) from (select 1/0 as test); it will return a value 1 coz the subquery is creating a table with a value null which means count will become 1.
1/0 gives u null instead of infinity in sql.

Comment: it has to be a comment not the post but im a new member so i cannot comment ri8 now that`s why i posted it.